# Strip out content from File in Local Directory using Node JS

Tags: html, node.js

Currently I have html files in a folder (70,000) that contain static content that I want to pull out. The content sits in a div with the ID 'content'. I figured I could just have nodeJS iterate over each file, grab the file name and its content. I figured out the first piece, any suggestions on how to have nodejs open the files and grab the content sitting in a particular div (id="content").

I'm currently running a windows machine if that effects anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`cheerio`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)

```
var cheerio = require('cheerio'),
$ = cheerio.load(file_content);

// use it like jQuery
var div_content = $('#content').text();
```